# How to send google app engine log files per email?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I am trying to implement how to send google app engine log files per email!

Sending an email does not seem to be a big problem at all(google mail api)

but I do not know how to extract all log files?

Do you have an advice for me or even a good tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [LogService](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logservice/overview) API to extract your application's logs.